OnPropertyChanged in all object's properties
Im working with MVVM, i have a ClientClass object with many properties (~50). So, in my view i have a Picker that is binded to the Client.ClientType property, and the same property binded to an Image icon like, that change depending on the Client.ClientType value. The problem is if i change that value, the OnPropertyChanged is not triggering, it only does if Client is assigned a whole new value like Client = new ClientClass().
I know i can wrap the property and force it like this:
public int ClientType {
    get => client.ClientType;
    set {
        if (client.ClientType == value) return;
        client.ClientType = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Client));
    }
}

but i wont do it for all properties.
So, there is a "simple" way to make all properties be like this without declare each one separately?
Simplified code example:
public class BaseVM : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    bool isBusy;
    string? title;
            
    public bool IsBusy {
        get => isBusy;
        set {
            if (isBusy == value) return;
            isBusy = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
            
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? name = null) =>
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}


public class ClientEditorVM : BaseVM {
    private ClientClass client;
    public ClientClass Client{
        get => client;
        set {
            if (client.Equals(value)) return;
            client = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

// this works, but repeat 50 times??
public int ClientType {
    get => client.ClientType;
    set {
        if (client.ClientType == value) return;
        client.ClientType = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Client));
    }
}


    public ClientEditorVM(ClientClass c){
        Client = c;
    }
}

public class ClientClass {
    public int ID { get; }
    public int ClientType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    ...
    // like 50 properties with no OnPropertyChanged implementation. Cant modify this.
}


use Fody

@Jason This is not the correct way of doing it in MAUI

So, there is a "simple" way to make all properties be like this without declare each one separately? Unfortunately, no. However, there are some workarounds to reduce the amount of boilerplate required. I have linked your question to a duplicate explaining those workarounds in detail.

@Heinzi This is a valid question in .NET MAUI and there is a way to do this please reopen this so i can answer

@FreakyAli: OK, go ahead. :-)

@Heinzi Thanks man appreciate your quick response, may be answer might be useful to you as well :)

The easiest way to do this is with the CommunityToolkit MVVM to avoid writing all the biolerplate code and focus on the actual task:
Install the NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm
Once installed you can basically define an ObserveableProperty in your Model/ViewModel that will basically work like you want it to, The only catch is that your BaseClass be it Model or ViewModel should inherit from ObserveableObject and then you need to set the class you wanna use it as partial so that the attributes can be converted to properties in the Toolkit generated partial class.
More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty
So now all you need to do is define private fields with the attributes and the rest is handled by the partial's in the background generated class
Define it as Observable this is how your current code would look:
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

public partial class BaseVM : ObservableObject 
{

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool isBusy;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string? title;
}


public class ClientEditorVM : BaseVM 
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private YourType whatever;
}


And now you should be able to access the properties like so:
var clientVm = new ClientVm();
client.IsBusy = true;
client.Whatever = new Whatever();

These will work as full-fleged properties more information in the above link
Highly recommend the other things in the community toolkit mvvm as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/

CommunityToolkit is tecnically an addon to write less code, it do exactly the same. The problem is not the access to read the properties, when the ´ClientEditorVM ´ is created it has some data that shows in the view. The issue is if you change a property value of that object, it not change the other views that has the same binding. So, if i have a 'Picker' binded to the ´Client.ClientType ´, and a ´Label´ also binded to it, when you change the value from the ´Picker´ the ´Label´ is not updated.

@Abelucho Can you add an example of this in your question(The view side label and picker whatever), i will show you how to do what you are looking for, I already know the answer just want to be sure that i understand your question

@Abelucho: The problem is that the Client class you use for binding does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Unfortunately, C# currently does not offer a better solution than to manually create a "wrapper class" in that case. If you're not afraid of reflection, you might try to adapt this Bindable class to use a nested object instead of a Dictionary as a storage, which would reduce the properties in your wrapper class to one-liners.

@FreakyAli: OP does not want to store the values in ClientVm. OP wants to forward property access to ClientClass, which does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

I think what he needs to do is set his BindingMode to TwoWay on the controls that he want to get affected

@FreakyAli: I'm pretty sure that that's not going to help. The binding works, the value gets written to the property. It's just that the UI does not get notified that the value has changed.

Yeah and i think he wants the UI to get notified...

@Heinzi that is exactly the problem. And worse, this class can be inherited... reason why im trying to find some other way tha wrap all properties...

You can report it on maui github, to ask a feature request.
